Sudden RPS Spike When a Locust Worker Fails to Send Heartbeat
Description:
We are experiencing a critical issue with Locust during our performance tests. Our setup includes 170 Locust worker agents and a Locust master. The tests aim to simulate up to 250,000 concurrent users.
Issue:
During the performance test, if a Locust worker fails to send a heartbeat, the Locust master marks the worker as missing and attempts to redistribute the load. This redistribution results in a sudden and drastic increase in RPS, which spikes from around 3,000 RPS to 10,000 RPS almost instantly. This surge in RPS causes significant instability in our test environment.
Detailed Logs and Behavior:
Locust Master Log:
timestamp: "2024-06-01 13:54:28.339788"
message: "Worker locust-worker-55b58bc866-b8f9t_b8f6a2c57e8049f88fd73e3049e67644 failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing."
timestamp: "2024-06-01 13:54:28.431401"
message: "Sending spawn jobs of 250000 users at 140.00 spawn rate to 169 ready workers"
Worker Log:
continues executing requests, then:
timestamp: "2024-06-01 13:56:03.203586"
message: "CPU usage above 90%! This may constrain your throughput and may even give inconsistent response time measurements! See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-distributed.html for how to distribute the load over multiple CPU cores or machines"
Observations:
The spike in RPS appears immediately after the master attempts to redistribute the load.
The worker that failed to send the heartbeat logs high CPU usage, but this log entry appears after it was marked as missing.
The sudden spike in load causes many users to fail, resulting in a rapid increase in error rates.
Configuration:
Number of Users: 250,000
Number of Workers: 170
Spawn Rate: 140.00 users per second
Worker Resource Utilization: CPU usage around 0.3-0.5 out of 1 core, RAM usage 300MB out of 2GB under normal conditions.
Questions:
Is there a recommended way to handle the sudden redistribution of load more gracefully in Locust?
Are there configuration settings that can help smooth out the spike in RPS when a worker goes missing?
Could this issue be related to how Locust handles worker failures, and is there a fix or workaround for this?
Steps to Reproduce:
Set up Locust with a master and 170 worker agents.
Configure the test to simulate 250,000 concurrent users.
Observe the behavior when a worker fails to send a heartbeat.
Impact:
This issue causes significant instability during our performance tests, making it challenging to achieve reliable results. Any guidance or recommendations to address this would be greatly appreciated.
I tried increasing the number of load agents. But this problem sometimes occurs even under less load.

SO is hard for this type of conversations, maybe try Slack instead?
Anyways, the root cause for your problem is most likely the worker running out of CPU, but without your locustfile it is impossible to know why. Are you doing regular HTTP requests? Try switching to FastHttpUser.

how to ask a good question:
how to ask

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
